# Apache Beam | Python | Dataflow - How to join BigQuery' collections with different keys?

Tags: join, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I've faced the following problem.
I'm trying to use INNER JOIN with two tables from Google BigQuery on Apache Beam (Python) for a specific situation. However, I haven't found a native way to deal with it easily.

This query output I'm going to fill a third table on Google BigQuery, for this situation I really need to query it on Google Dataflow. The first table (client) key is the "id" column, and the second table (purchase) key is the "client_id" column.

1.Tables example (consider 'client_table.id = purchase_table.client_id'):

client_table

```
| id |    name     | country |
|----|-------------|---------|
| 1  | first user  |   usa   |
| 2  | second user |   usa   |
```

purchase_table

```
| id |  client_id  |  value  |
|----|-------------|---------|
| 1  |      1      |   15    |
| 2  |      1      |   120   |
| 3  |      2      |   190   |
```

2.Code I'm trying to develop (problem in the second line of 'output'):

```
options = {'project': PROJECT,
           'runner': RUNNER,
           'region': REGION,
           'staging_location': 'gs://bucket/temp',
           'temp_location': 'gs://bucket/temp',
           'template_location': 'gs://bucket/temp/test_join'}
pipeline_options = beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **options)
pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options = pipeline_options)

query_results_1 = (
 pipeline 
    | 'ReadFromBQ_1' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query="select id as client_id, name from client_table", use_standard_sql=True)))

query_results_2 = (
 pipeline 
    | 'ReadFromBQ_2' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query="select * from purchase_table", use_standard_sql=True)))

output = ( {'query_results_1':query_results_1,'query_results_2':query_results_2} 
    | 'join' >> beam.GroupBy('client_id')
    | 'writeToBQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        table=TABLE,
        dataset=DATASET,
        project=PROJECT,
        schema=SCHEMA,
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))

pipeline.run()
```

3.Equivalent desired output in SQL:

```
SELECT a.name, b.value * from client_table as a INNER JOIN purchase_table as b on a.id = b.client_id;
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Dear @philipxy, could you tell me if it is better? There is no error message, because problem is on code creation, I'm tying to put a better explanation for DB Tables.

Comment: It's good that the images are gone. But that's all you've done. We can't cut & paste & run right now. Etc for a [mre]. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Imho, I believe the question is good as it is for those who know Beam and the posted code is enough to have an idea of what they want to achieve and where their issue relies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use either a `CoGroupByKey` or side inputs (as a broadcast join) depending on your key cardinality. If you have a few keys with many elements each, I suggest the broadcast join.

The first thing you'd need to do is to add a key to your PCollections after the BQ read:

```
kv_1 = query_results_1 | Map(lambda x: (x["id"], x))
kv_2 = query_results_1 | Map(lambda x: (x["client_id"], x))
```

Then you can just do the CoGBK or broadcast join. As an example (since it would be easier to understand), I am going to use the code from this session of [Beam College](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYD40js20a4&t=1675s). Note that in your example the Value of the KV is a dictionary, so you'd need to make some modifications.

Data

```
jobs = [
    ("John", "Data Scientist"),
    ("Rebecca", "Full Stack Engineer"),
    ("John", "Data Engineer"),
    ("Alice", "CEO"),
    ("Charles", "Web Designer"),
    ("Ruben", "Tech Writer")
]

hobbies = [
    ("John", "Baseball"),
    ("Rebecca", "Football"),
    ("John", "Piano"),
    ("Alice", "Photoshop"),
    ("Charles", "Coding"),
    ("Rebecca", "Acting"),
    ("Rebecca", "Reading")
]
```

Join with CGBK

```
def inner_join(element):
  name = element[0]
  jobs = element[1]["jobs"]
  hobbies = element[1]["hobbies"]
  joined =  [{"name": name,
              "job": job,
              "hobbie": hobbie}
             for job in jobs for hobbie in hobbies]
  return joined


jobs_create = p | "Create Jobs" >> Create(jobs)
hobbies_create = p | "Create Hobbies" >> Create(hobbies)

cogbk = {"jobs": jobs_create, "hobbies": hobbies_create} | CoGroupByKey()

join = cogbk | FlatMap(inner_join)
```

Broadcast join with Side Inputs

```
def broadcast_inner_join(element, side_input):
  name = element[0]
  job = element[1]
  hobbies = side_input.get(name, [])

  joined =  [{"name": name,
              "job": job,
              "hobbie": hobbie}
             for hobbie in hobbies]
  return joined

hobbies_create = (p | "Create Hobbies" >> Create(hobbies) 
                    | beam.GroupByKey()
                )

jobs_create = p | "Create Jobs" >> Create(jobs)

boardcast_join = jobs_create | FlatMap(broadcast_inner_join, 
                                        side_input=pvalue.AsDict(hobbies_create))
```